# Unable to fetch data using Http Get request in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to fetch data in AngularJS using Http Get request. I have created a separate controller.js file where I have implemented Http get service.

I have created a database.json file within the app.When I am trying to run my app on http-server, I am unable to fetch data from the data file created.

### I am getting the following error in my console.

[image]

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Angular JS -->  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<!--Route Guard -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Controller.js -->
<script src="controller.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="datactrl">
    <ul>
        <h4>Name And Age Of The persons</h4>
        <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
            {{ person.Name+ ':' + person.Age }}          
        </li>           
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

`controller.js`:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", [ ]);

app.controller('datactrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://127.0.0.1/AngularJS/HttpGet/database.json')
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.persons = response.records;
    });
});
```

`database.json`:

```json
{
    "records": [
    {
    "Name" : "asd",
    "Age" : "20"
    },

    {
    "Name" : "asd",
    "Age" : "20"
    },

    {
    "Name" : "asd",
    "Age" : "20"
    }

    ]
}
```

Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue..?

Comment: Give relative path for the `database.json` file instead of providing absolute path

Comment: I also tried giving the path as file:///D:/AngularJS/DemoJS/assets/database.json... but still the same error

Comment: Where is the `database.json`, it might be in your project folder so give the relative path from your controller file for that URL

Comment: oh sorry .... missed that path .. i will correct

Comment: You can also take a referece from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33753986/7053190

Comment: Please refer this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41993170/4800690

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: file:///D:/AngularJS/HttpGet/database.json ... this is the actual path of my json file .... but still its giving me the same error

Comment: @AashishChaubey... the error is being removed now but still data is not fetched.

Comment: Can you open that url directly in your browser?

Comment: Also should be `$scope.persons = response.data.records;`. The `response` object is not the data

Comment: yes i can open file:///D:/AngularJS/HttpGet/database.json ........ this url and can see my data

Comment: Stop using `file://` protocol. Can you open it at same path shown in request? `'http://127.0.0.1/AngularJS/HttpGet/database.json'`

Comment: can you give url as `window.location.origin + '/whatever/your/path/is'`

I think this should work!

Comment: @charlietfl....... not its showing me unable to connect.

Comment: @Heena, please show us the error log!

Comment: there is no error in my console..............

Comment: when I added app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);............... the error is removed

Comment: Then problem is bad path. What is web path you open page with?

Comment: It must throw something in the developer console right?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8083/.............this is where i get my page

Comment: Well something not right server side. You should be able to open that web path to json file right in browser. Until you sort that out and pass working url to `$http` we can't solve issue for you

Comment: @AashishChaubey......... the earlier error is removed when i added app.config.......

Comment: Look in the developer console and send me a screenshot of it. I will be able to get it for you. It is just that I am not able to understand. And if my answer is helpful please mark it useful. It will be helpful for the others as well

Comment: All about json path you are failed to provide right json path. Can you post your project structure screen.I want to see where your json is currently placed ?